# Mass dimension of coupling constants in various dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, spacetime-dimensions, dimensional-analysis, yang-mills

Just a quick question: Suppose I want to consider QED or YM in 4 dimensions we always say that the coupling constants are dimensionless and that the field then has a specific mass dimension. What happens if we change the dimensions we are considering? Do the mass dimensions of the fields then change or do the coupling constants become dimensionful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do the mass dimensions of the fields then change or do the coupling
>   constants become dimensionful?

As checked by @Funzies, the mass dimension of the fields change, for instance the mass dimension for scalar bosonic fields is $[\phi]=\frac{d-2}{2}$. This is because you have always a kinetic term $(\partial \phi)^2$ in the Lagrangian, and that the Lagrangian hass mass dimension $d$, such as the mass dimension of the action is zero.

When you have in the Lagrangian , an interacting term of kind $\alpha ~\phi^p$, you must have $[\alpha]+ p [\phi]= d$, so finally $[\alpha] = d - \frac{p(d-2)}{2}$

For instance, in $d=4$ dimensions, a interacting term in $\alpha ~\phi^4$ has a dimensionless coupling constant $\alpha$. For other dimensions, this coupling constant is dimensionfull, for instance, in $d=6$ dimensions, $[\alpha]=-2$

Answer (score 3):

The action $S$ must always be dimensionless. In $d$ dimensions it looks like:
$$
S = \int d^dx \mathcal{L},
$$
with $\mathcal{L}$ the Lagrange density. Recall that $[x] = -1$, this follows from $[x,p]=i$ (commutator with $\hbar := 1$), such that $[x] = -[p] = -1$, thus we must have: $[\mathcal{L}] = d$. A standard mass term would be $m^2\phi^2$, so the dimension of the field becomes $[\phi] = 1/2(d-2)$.